# Set number of bins for histogram directly in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'd like to feed `geom_histogram` the number of bins for my histogram instead of controlling bins through `binwidth`. [The documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html) says I can do this by setting the `bins` argument. But when I run

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + stat_bin(bins = 5)
```

I get an output message with 30 bins,  as if I didn't specify binwidth at all.

> stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.

I've tried feeding this argument to `stat_bin` and `qplot` with the same problem. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using ggplot2 version 1.0.1.

Comment: can you share your data please

Comment: What version of ggplot are you using?

Comment: @mtoto I've changed the question so it uses generic data

Comment: @Heroka I've added version information to the question. I'm using version 1.0.1. Would R version info be useful too, in this case?

Comment: If you update to ggplot 2.0 the stat_bin(bins = x) command should work.

Comment: works for me. consider updating ggplot and/or restarting your r session.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for ggplot 2.0

Comment: It works fine for me, but oddly: it always produces one more bin than I specify. An index-0 bug? (ggplot 2.0.0)

Comment: Oh interesting, @alistaire -- yes, same result illustrated below

Comment: Opened [an issue report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1487) on GitHub.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just pass `bins=x` directly

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10000))

ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram()
```

Produces this (with warning "`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`."):

[image]

And this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
```

Produces:

[image]

Using ggplot2 version 2.0.0

Comment: Hat tip to @bouncyball, apparently you commented to the same effect while I was writing this