# Specifying bins in histogram on the x- axis using ggplot2 in r

Tags: r

In am plotting histogram in r an I want to specify my bins but I am getting some else.

This is my lenght data

```
pss <-
structure(list(LengthSize = c(48, 39, 94, 30, 81, 49, 44, 85, 
44, 55, 45, 47, 44, 43, 42, 44, 76, 42, 65, 43, 43, 90, 105, 
32, 31, 43, 36, 65, 21, 15, 113, 113, 44, 46, 94, 90, 95, 37, 
25, 72, 49, 46, 48, 49, 49, 44, 50, 48, 37, 37, 55, 60, 65, 30, 
22, 26, 43, 43, 43, 43, 18, 67, 110, 64, 28, 29, 38, 37, 38, 
37, 38, 70, 58, 65, 55, 60, 40, 22, 68, 88, 88, 32, 44, 86, 37, 
38, 67, 52, 48, 123, 50, 114, 37, 38, 39, 41, 60, 55, 50, 99, 
57, 44, 45, 45, 51, 44, 45, 37, 39, 43, 43, 50, 51, 34, 42, 44, 
46, 67, 67, 56, 56, 57, 56, 47, 65, 66, 43, 41, 69, 45, 114, 
60, 55, 37, 88, 85, 39, 39, 46, 50, 60, 44, 77, 61, 68, 46, 114, 
51, 105, 48, 95, 32, 40, 28, 42, 47, 46, 48, 50, 96, 45, 47, 
118, 55, 60, 34, 118, 39, 52, 119, 40, 55, 60, 55, 59, 102, 73, 
42, 78, 56, 74, 102, 88, 38, 36, 33, 34, 41, 120, 50, 46, 79, 
98, 65, 40, 45, 42, 50, 61, 44)), 
row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code  in ggplot2.

```
pss %>% 
ggplot(data = pss,breaks = 25,xlim = c(0,528,11), mapping = aes(x = LengthSize )) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, col = "black", fill = "grey")
```

Comment: Please log in and take a look at the data in your question. It is not very pleasant to the eyes. Please format your post appropriately. It's also better to provide data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: Just pass `bins=no_bins_you_want` inside your  `geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, bins=50, col = "black", fill = "grey")`. Experiment with different numbers till you find the one appealing to your desire.

Comment: You don't need the pipe `pss %>%` and then `ggplot(data = pss, etc)`. Use just one of them. (Suggestion: not the pipe.)

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right track, just modify your script as follows. You can experiment with `binwidth` and `bins`. You can easily modify or remove the `title`, `xlab` and `ylab` if you don't want them.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pss, mapping = aes(LengthSize)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 3, bins=50, col = "black", fill = "grey") + ggtitle("My plot title") + xlab("My X axis label - length size") + ylab("Y axis label - Fequency count") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

On the basis of the sample data above, the script produces the following histogram. 
[image: hist_bins]

Comment: Deepseefan I am trying your code but getting the same plot I have been producing my bins are 100, 200, and so on

Comment: @RobertWilson, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774120/set-number-of-bins-for-histogram-directly-in-ggplot/34774372) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ Deepseefan I am seeing decimals as my bins instead of the actual bins so it doesn't help.

Comment: @RobertWilson can you edit your post and attach your output?

Comment: the plot above represent my data but it is not reflecting in my code when I run it.

Comment: @RobertWilson what does it produce? I'm curious to see the output produced at your end. Is `ggplot2` installed and loaded on your system?

Comment: I have ggplot2 installed but I am trying to paste the plot to show what I am talking about